# Python (pandas) - How to group values in one column and then delete or keep that group based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas dataset:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| dog | RE |
| dog | RE FX |
| cat | RE BA |
| mouse | AQ |
| mouse | RE FX |
| salmon | AQ |

Essentially what I would like to do is group the values in Column 1 and then either keep or delete them based on the values in Column 2. So for example, I want to delete all values in a group in Column 1 if ANY of the corresponding rows in Column 2 are "RE" or "RE BA". Based on the dataset above, the output would be the following:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| mouse | AQ |
| mouse | RE FX |
| salmon | AQ |

I am struggling with this because although I understand how to drop rows based on whether they contain a specific value, I don't understand how to drop entire groups based on whether ANY of the rows in that group contain a specific value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby` then `filter`

```py
out = df.groupby("Column 1").filter(lambda df: ~df['Column 2'].isin(["RE", "RE BA"]).any())
```

```
print(out)

  Column 1 Column 2
3    mouse       AQ
4    mouse    RE FX
5   salmon       AQ
```